# Get terminal output after system() execution in R

Tags: linux, r

If I run an R script which contains a system function call similar to :

```
x<-system("ls -t -r | tail -n 1") ,
```

x will be 0 if the command is executed properly, different than 0 if there is an error.
How can I save the output from the terminal in R, while executing the script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `intern` attribute to true.

```
x<-system("ls -t -r | tail -n 1", intern=TRUE)
```